# Mess with response Values: php->system->bash->python3

Tags: python-3.x, bash

I'm in trouble with response Values of a phyton script (face_detection).

If I run it directly in the console, everything works pretty well.
If I run it as Part of a shell script, no response apear.

I already checked:
1.) image and scripts are usable by user **www-data** (at the end it should run as system-request from php). I checked it by **sudo -u www-data ..**

2.) Also also checked a much simpler command ("ls -l $1"), which brings the expected reponse. So only the python script doesnt work (as sub from bash script).

Now, I have NO Idea what else may be wrong in my code. Any Help would be very apreciated!

Regards Rene´

Some Background info:
Ubuntu 14.4, Kernel 3.13.0-24-generic
PHP 5.5.9-1ubuntu4.26 
GNU bash, version 4.3.8(1)-release 
face_recognise (https://github.com/ageitgey/face_recognition) V 1.2.3

on terminal:

```
/usr/local/bin/face_detection /var/www/1545249278.jpg
```

response is:

```
/var/www/1545249278.jpg,166,879,701,344 (= correct)
```

via bash-script:

```
#!/bin/bash

facePosition=`/bin/bash -c \"/usr/bin/python3 /usr/local/bin/face_detection $1\"`

printf $facePosition
```

response is: (None/empty = wrong)

I also checked this variations:

```
facePosition=`/bin/bash -c \"/usr/local/bin/face_detection $1 | /usr/bin/cut -d ',' -f2\"`
facePosition=`/bin/bash -c \"/usr/bin/python3 /usr/local/bin/face_detection $1\"`
facePosition=`env python3 /usr/local/bin/face_detection $1`
```

Comment: Why the `php` tag?

Comment: Because I call the bash script from php via **system**.